# Where are laravel cache files stored?

Tags: caching, laravel-5.4, backend

I have an application and my cache driver is

```
In config/cache.php
 'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

In my .env
 CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

In my application if I cache something, then where these cache files are stored?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cache will be stored in the `storage/framework/cache`

If this is not working then make sure you have sufficient folder permission to access it.

If you want to access it. Simply access it by `key`like:

```
Cache::get('key');
```

Comment: I want know `storage/framework/cache` folder backup required when taking backup of laravel live site??

Comment: so how do you store?

Comment: @ichimaru Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 10);

Comment: And `php artisan config:cache` is stored at *bootstrap/cache/config.php*.

Answer (score 6):

Should be at:

```
storage/framework/cache
```

Checked it ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the cache folder for Laravel 4 and 5.

```
function getCacheFolder()
{
  // Check version & get folder for Laravel 4
  $app = app();
  if ($app) {
    $ver = $app->VERSION();
    $v = explode('.', $ver);
    if ($v[1] <= 4) {
      return storage_path('cache');
    }
  }

  // Laravel 5
  return storage_path('framework/cache'),
}
```